# Creating a torus with more than 256 segments with nearly 1km radius?

Tags: mesh

Is there a reasonably simple way to create a torus with minimal vertices and faces (that is no artifacts from merging extrusions) with more than 256 segments (in my case 1800 major segments and 360 minor segments) with a major radius of about 900m and a minor radius of about 50m?

Comment: It is possible, but this kind of heavy geometry may kill your computer. Are you trying to make a hyperrealistic, ultradetailed donut? ;).

Comment: Maybe curves would suit you better

Comment: The computer has enough power to render many more polygons than that (it's already got a few dozen objects with similar polygon counts and scale on screen) - just trying to find a way to construct it that doesn't add excess vertices or polygons and doesn't involve me selectively filling each face - going for the inside half of the torus with a flat exterior so I'm already going to have to manually fill in 1800 polygons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by adding a circle, with 360 vertices, a radius of 50, and the *Fill Type* set to *Nothing*.
[image: Add circle options]
In edit mode rotate the circle along the Y axis by 90°. Then move the circle 900 along the Y axis.

Last add a *Screw* modifier, with *Steps* and  *Render Steps* set to *1800*. Leave all other modifier settings to default.
[image: screw modifier]
You now have a torus with 648,000 vertices and faces; 1800 major segments and 360 minor segments.